# Tickcount and milliseconds in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I convert from TickCounts to Milliseconds?

this is what I used:

```
long int before = GetTickCount();
long int after = GetTickCount();
```

I want the difference of it in seconds.

Comment: Danny, your question isn't clear. Do you want seconds or milliseconds? When you edit your question to clarify, please also include evidence that you've read the documentation for the function you're calling. If you've read it but haven't understood, that's OK, but then please describe what it is you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int seconds = (after - before) /1000;
```

Answer (score 6):

for more precision, there is also [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
int seconds = (after - before + 500) / 1000;
```

or:

```
double seconds = (after - before) / 1000.0;
```

Comment: Why "+ 500"? The OP didn't specify whole seconds, so why rounding up?

Comment: Beware the integer division, it doesn't generate a floating point value.  Adding 500 doesn't round up, it rounds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what OS/platform you're using, but there should be a call that returns the tick time in milliseconds.

```
time = after - before * <tick time in milliseconds>;
```

---

Edit:

I see that this is a Windows function that returns milliseconds already. The other answers are better.

Answer (score 1):

[GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx) returns the time in milliseconds. so `(after - before)/<milli equivalent>` should give you time in seconds

Comment: "milli equivalent", of course, is 1000, since a millisecond is 1/1000 of a second. :-)